# Using QGIS module in Python (PyCharm)

Tags: python, qgis

I've been trying to write a script for QGIS in Python, but cannot get pass the point of trying to import QGIS module.
Tried everything, fresh install of Python, QGIS and PyCharm; changing the interpreter to QGIS Python; updating pip...

I keep getting:
Error: Could not find a version thwt satisfies the requirement qgis(from versions: none)
Error: No matching distribution found for qgis

In PyCharm I just get "unresolved reference 'qgis' "...

I've been driven mad by this, fighting with it for a week now...

Thanks for the help...